# Return num instead of int in an OCaml Function

Tags: int, ocaml

I have a tail-recursive factorial function, that receives an `int` and returns `int`, but I want it to return `num`. How can I do it? Here is the code:

```
     let fact n =
         let rec aux f i =
                 if i = 0 then f
                 else aux (f*i) (i-1)
         in aux 1 n;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want type `int -> num` you need to convert at appropriate places. If you want to compute large factorials, your `aux` function will have to be `num -> int -> num`.

Here's one way to do this:

```
let fact n =
    let rec aux accum i =
        if i = 0 then accum
        else aux Num.(accum */ num_of_int i) (i - 1)
in
aux (Num.num_of_int 1) n
```

You can play with moving the scope of `Num.( ... )` around to get something nicer looking.

(This was tested with OCaml 4.00.1.)

Comment: Now the mistake is different. It gives me an Error:This expression has type Num.num but an expression was expected of type int :(

Comment: (Sorry, I was using try.ocamlpro.com which has a non-standard OCaml interpreter. I'm fixing my answer....)

Comment: No problem, thanks Sir. In college i have to use OCaml 3.12 so, i can't test last edit.

Comment: I just compiled my code with OCaml 3.12 and it works fine. Did you try it? At any rate in the big picture you just need to make sure you convert between `int` and `num` as appropriate, and refer to the `Num` module explicitly where required. Your basic code is fine.

Comment: Thank you sir! The problem was that i wasn't including Num's library. Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the aux function already already is `int -> int` and you don't need to modify it then you just need to modify returned value:

```
in num_of_int (aux 1 n);;
```

Comment: I tried that but it returns me an error. 
        Error:Reference to undefined global 'Num'

Comment: @BreixoCamiñaFernández: you have to either `open Num` or use `Num.num_of_int`.

Comment: @BreixoCamiñaFernández: if you are entering code into running top-level, don't forget to load nums library: `#load "nums.cma";;`.

Comment: That was the problem, I forgot Num's library! Thank you so much @barti_ddu :)

Comment: Except that if you do that the intermediate computations over `int` in `aux` will overflow pretty quickly.